# Compile and deploy an Ethereum Viper Smart Contract automatically

Tags: ethereum

In there any way to compile and deploy Viper Smart Contract automatically to some custom chain (not tester chain from ethereum.tools)

According to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethereum/viper/issues/459) and two posts that I found ([this one](https://www.reggie.io/blog/deploying-ethereum-viper/) and [that one](https://www.mikeshultz.com/deploying-ethereum-viper-smart-contract.html)), the best option is to compile contract and then insert into geth manually.

Can anyone share their solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/viper/issues/459) you provided - you can achieve it by using [web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py) library and a [Viper](https://github.com/ethereum/viper) library itself.
Here is an example of a script which probably covers your needs:

```python
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from viper import compiler
from web3.contract import ConciseContract
from time import sleep

example_contract = open('./path/to/contract.v.py', 'r')
contract_code = example_contract.read()
example_contract.close()

cmp = compiler.Compiler()
contract_bytecode = cmp.compile(contract_code).hex()
contract_abi = cmp.mk_full_signature(contract_code)

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
web3.personal.unlockAccount('account_addr', 'account_pwd', 120)

# Instantiate and deploy contract
contract_bytecode = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi, bytecode=contract_bytecode)

# Get transaction hash from deployed contract
tx_hash = contract_bytecode.deploy(transaction={'from': 'account_addr', 'gas': 410000})

# Waiting for contract to be delpoyed
i = 0  
while i < 5:
    try:
        # Get tx receipt to get contract address
        tx_receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
        contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
        break  # if success, then exit the loop
    except:
        print("Reading failure for {} time(s)".format(i + 1))
        sleep(5+i)
        i = i + 1
        if i >= 5:
             raise Exception("Cannot wait for contract to be deployed")

# Contract instance in concise mode
contract_instance = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi, contract_address, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)

# Calling contract method
print('Contract value: {}'.format(contract_instance.some_method()))
```